# Xcode, remove files from a branch so they don't have to be merged?

Tags: xcode, git, xcode6

I've accidentally commited my cocoapods project from my workspace into a branch.

Now that I need to merge the branch back to the master branch, I can't proceed.

I've been through all all of the files and accepted the changes in each files (which took quite a long time), however the merge aborted, with a message saying it couldn't overwrite local files.

I'd like to remove cocoapods and not have changes under git. However, I'm not sure how to proceed. I've seen that you can remove find at the command line, but I'm concerned as I'm in a branch.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I physically deleted my pods folder, then committed the deleted files. I was then able to merge :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is probably the filter-branch feature of Git to remove some files from every commits: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch

Try something like below on your branch:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf <yourCocoapods>' HEAD
```

Comment: @pierrefevier I get the following warning 'Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/jm.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist: needs merge
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.'

Comment: You need to clean your workspace by stashing your work before launching filter.